# fatal: Could not change back to '/root': Permission denied

Tags: permissions, marytts

I'm trying to install MaryTTS  on ubuntu 16.4.
but when I hit the line

```
sudo -u mary git clone https://github.com/marytts/marytts.git /local/mary/marytts
```

**fatal: Could not change back to '/root': Permission denied**

*link tutorial*, and [link](https://github.com/marytts/marytts/wiki/Local-MaryTTS-Server-Installation)

Comment: I have a little advance but still an error

$ cd /tmp
$ sudo -u mary git clone https://github.com/marytts/marytts.git /local/mary/marytts
$ cd /local/mary/marytts
$ sudo -u mary git fetch --tags
$ sudo -u mary git checkout v5.2
$ sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jdk maven

$ sudo -u mary mvn package
BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running command you are probably in homedir ~ (/root) so before sudo command switch to e.g. /tmp which has more open permissions

`cd /tmp
sudo -u mary git clone https://github.com/marytts/marytts.git /local/mary/marytts`